# floating point exception is thrown when casting double to int

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, floating-point, integer-overflow

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <fenv.h>

int main()
{
    feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);
    double d = INT_MAX * 2.0f;
    int i = (int)d; // it throws here fp exception and terminates. Why ?

    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First thing that can be noticed here is that casting double to an int causes overflow of the temporary value (it is more than `INT_MAX`), which is of course in general undefined behavour.

But I'm more concerned about the fact that FP exception here can be trapped by passing `FE_INVALID` constant flag to the `feenableexcept` function.

From the [cpp_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) I can see that `FE_INVALID` has nothing to do with overflowing at all.

Why then integer overflowing here causes fp exception ?

Is that because of the nature of UB ?

Comment: Is `INT_MAX * 2.0f` representable as `float` ?  Why do you use `2.0f` rather than `2.0` ?

Comment: @SidS Somewhat odd choice indeed, but it fits. `FLT_MAX` is usually 3.40282e+38.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sure, but the precision will be lacking ?  `INT_MAX * 2.0f / 2` is probably not equal to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @SidS Hm? It sure is (in float arithmetic of course). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afabcfad39a3ffc9 Multiplication by two just adjusts the exponent. Also, I don't see how accuracy is even relevant here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, on my system this code: `cout << INT_MAX << ' ' << int(INT_MAX * 2.0f / 2) << ' ' << int(INT_MAX * 2.0 / 2) << endl;` outputs `2147483647 -2147483648 2147483647`

Comment: @SidS I'm sorry, it seems I am completely missing your point here. How is this relevant? (And btw, while I don't see how it matters: [no repro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QgDhjnUbO0mp1ZO0). As one would expect from IEEE-754 systems.) (Edit: pasted wrong link)

Comment: Just a caution about a common source of confusion. A floating-point exception is not a C++ exception, so it isn’t thrown. Floating-point folks call errors exceptions, but they’re two different things.

Comment: @Pete Becker yes but it is possible to handle it in C/C++, as it is just SIGFPE signal sending to a programm when it is enabled for trapping, just like SIGSEGV I bet

Comment: As `int feenableexcept(int excepts);` returns an `int` to "return zero on success and nonzero if an error occurred.", it would be prudent to report `feenableexcept(FE_INVALID)` return value as a first debugging step.

Comment: @BaummitAugen `INT_MAX * 2.0f` causes a conversion of `INT_MAX` to `float` _or wider_ FP type prior to multiplication.  When it converts to `float`, an inexact conversion is common.  OP's use of `2.0f` would be less distracting than `2.0`.

Comment: @chux To be brutally honest, I still haven't understood what we are even arguing about. Afaict, having some (any) floating point number sufficiently big to trigger the FP exception is all that's important; I cannot see how the precision is relevant here. If the question was about the "Inexact" exception, sure. But so far, this is just going over my head.

Comment: @BaummitAugen  Agree the precision issue is certainly a side one.  The  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582928/floating-point-exception-is-thrown-when-casting-double-to-int?noredirect=1#comment95963771_54582928) here suggested your interest in exploring  it though. If irrelevant to you, might want to let others, like OP, address  Sid S [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582928/floating-point-exception-is-thrown-when-casting-double-to-int?noredirect=1#comment95963675_54582928).

Comment: @chux The point of that comment was more that the "issue" is a non-issue, because `float` is big enough, too. I guess that was not clear. I did not mean to stop anyone from debating this, but people kept pinging me and I did not understand what exactly they wanted to argue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is UB by the C++ standard, this is of course not specified by the language itself.

However, your implementation follows IEEE-754 – the standard most implementations base their floating point behavior on – in this regard, which states:

> When a NaN or infinite operand cannot be represented in the destination format and this cannot otherwise
>   be indicated, the invalid operation exception shall be signaled. **When a numeric operand would convert to
>   an integer outside the range of the destination format, the invalid operation exception shall be signaled if
>   this situation cannot otherwise be indicated.**

(5.8 "Details of conversions from floating-point to integer formats", emphasis mine)

How those exceptions can be handled when signaled is left to the implementation; enabling a trap for them is one of the possibilities.

Further reading: [gcc's documentation on FP exceptions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Exceptions.html#FP-Exceptions)